# Buffer overflow with integers

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit, shift

I have a very basic question. Lets say I have two variables(uint16_t a, uint16_t b) and in memory they are aligned next to each other like a=> 0x0 => 0x15 and  b=> 0x16 to 0x31

Lets assume a = 0, b = 65535,

```
(1) if i increment b(b++), b will become 0 but will it affect 'a' 0th bit?
(2) if i right shift b( b = b << 1), will it affect 'a' ?
```

Thank you

Comment: no. unsigned overflow is well defined. signed overflow is undefined behavior so the result can be anything, but in real life overflowing b will not change a

Comment: "_Lets assume..."_ - ... that you tried it out yourself and that's why you're asking. Please share your findings.

Comment: Unh... That's a **LEFT** shift that you've asked about... and the answer is still "no". Operations on `a` or `b` will not affect the other unless you've ventured into UB with addressing issues...

Answer (score 2):

No, unless you are doing odd things with pointers or casts.

Answer (score 0):

## The answer is no.

`a` and `b` is a `uint16_t`, so it is of an unsigned type. And unsigned overflow (or wrap-around) is well-defined in C. It won't change the memory besides it.

Comment: Exactly, it will just go back to zero

Answer (score 0):

No, a correctly designed system will not have that happen. Also, I will point out that your numeral notation is incorrect by common convention. 0x is generally used to notate hexadecimal numbers, including in the C language, but from the context of your question, you are prefixing decimal base numbers with it for no apparent reason. For example, 0x31 is equal to 49 in decimal. And 16+16 is not equal to 49.